# Google currency search showing different results

Tags: php, curl, google-search

So the google currency converter (https://finance.google.com/finance/converter) stopped working about a week ago and my solution was to use google search instead (like https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=1+usd+to+ars) and extracting the data from there...

The thing is, when I go to https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=1+usd+to+ars from my browser, (just using those two currencies as an example) I get a value with 7 decimals... but when I go to that link from a php script using curl, I get a value with two decimals...

The relevant part in my script looks something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init ( "https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=1+usd+to+ars" );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$output = curl_exec ( $ch );
echo $output;
curl_close ( $ch );
```

which returns the source with two decimals as opposed to the 7 of my google search...

Why would there be such a difference?

Comment: Google has a notorious record for providing different results based on 'browser' ... I've seen different results on the same computer once using two versions of the same browser. So, relying on that to parse is going to be problematic. You may want to look into a daily/hourly pull from some place like https://currencylayer.com/ on their free plan.

Comment: As a side... when I go to that url you tested, I get 2 decimals in Chrome. As a side side, I'm not trying to sell currencylayer. I only use it on the free plan, works perfectly with a hourly cron dump to a mysql db. Set n forget.

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip...